# Automatically refresh Django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm wanting to automatically refresh/update a model in the admin page to show updated data. How can I modify the admin panel to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript for auto reload admin page.

create a file auto_reload.js and paste below code.

```
function autoRefreshPage() {
    window.location = window.location.href;
}
setInterval('autoRefreshPage()', 10000);
```

And add path of file in Media class of your modeladmin class.
This will refresh page after 10 sec.

admin.py

```
@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    class Media:
        js = [
            "admin/js/auto_reload.js",  # path of file
        ]
```